# access table data using .idb and .frm file.

Tags: mysql, database

I accessed .idb file from data store of mysql,even if database is password protected. 
So if we can access Mysql database using .idb and .frm file without password then whats the use of database password??

Answer (score 3):

it is important to consider that if you have physical access to the file system then all bets are off. there will always be some piece of 3rd party software etc that will unscramble some database file.

the point of a mysql password is to allow access through the allowed pathways to the MYSQL server.

to put that in context, a normal user or administrator of a website that is powered by php and mysql would never see or have access to the physical database files. The password level access set up in PHP and MySQL would only allow the application (php) to access what is required.

Securing the database files themselves should be done at the operating system level, granting the level of user access you require.